# Cordova emulate not running on Genymotion after SDK update

Tags: android, cordova, android-emulator, genymotion, android-sdk-tools

Using Genymotion version 2.2.2, Android SDK Tools 23(current), virtual box 4.3 installed and phone image Nexus 4 - android 4.4.2 installed.

So I was using SDK Tools 20(I guess) with eclipse. Genymotion was acting perfectly by then. Cordova was emulating the app in Genymotion. Then I installed android studio and update my sdk tools to 23. Installed selected packages. 4.4 is also installed.

Now Genymotion emulator opens perfectly but cordova isn't opening app in Genymotion. Rather it's searching for ADT for default SDK emulators.

```
 Cordova emulate android
```

This failed to open the app in Genymotion. I also tried to tweak the Genymotion SDK settings. Nothing helped.

What went wrong?? How to fix it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Got the answer from Genymotion team, cordova is treating Genymotion as an individual device(not emulator). So to install the app following command need to be given.

```
cordova run android
```

Comment: when i executed "cordova run android" i get this errror message "Error executing "adb devices": ADB server didn't ACK
* failed to start daemon *
error:"

Comment: guess: you didn't start the emulator first. you need to start genymotion first, then run those lines.